# Using retrofit to read string content from api

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Currently, I am using Retrofit to get data from api. But the format of data is a bit different from other format such as :

```
["tayl",["taylor swift","taylor swift kanye west","taylor swift famous","taylor swift mp3","taylor lautner","taylor swift wiki","taylor swift 1989","taylor hill","taylor swift 2016","taylor kinney"]]
```

So, I want to ask for the best solution to parse values to get a list as below if I want to use retrofit:

```
"taylor swift","taylor swift kanye west","taylor swift famous","taylor swift mp3","taylor lautner","taylor swift wiki","taylor swift 1989","taylor hill","taylor swift 2016","taylor kinney"
```

The content of the file above is the data which GoogleAutoComplete Api returned for me with the link below :

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=tayl
```

I implemented the code as below but it is not good:

```
  @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    })
    @GET("complete/search?")
    Call<ResponseBody> getAutoComplete(@Query(@Query("q")String query);
```

The below is response code which I am using:

```
  autoCompleteCall = googleApi.getAutoComplete(client, keyword);
    autoCompleteCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (response != null &&
                    response.body() != null) {
                    System.out.println(" String response======= " + response.body().toString());
                return;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }

    });
```

But the responsebody returned for me is null. 
Please help  me in this case.
Thanks.

Comment: This wont compile I think. Incorrect number of braces in `getAutoComplete()`. Also post the response code you receive. Whether  you get call on success or error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the API endpoint in an interface as follows:

```
@GET("complete/search")
Call<ResponseBody> getAutoComplete(
        @Query("client") String client,
        @Query("q") String query);
```

Make the network request as follows:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getAutoComplete("firefox", "tayl");

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            ResponseBody body = response.body();
            try {
                // autocompleteOptions => ["tayl",["taylor swift","taylor lautner",...
                String autocompleteOptions = body.string();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(autocompleteOptions).getJSONArray(1);
                // list => "taylor swift","taylor lautner",...
                ArrayList<String> list = GetAutocompleteOptions(jsonArray);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
     }
});

private ArrayList<String> GetAutocompleteOptions(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (jsonArray != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```